# Styling nvd3 Charts

Tags: css, svg, nvd3.js

I'm having some trouble styling this [nvd3 line chart](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sEtnB). I've got a lot of it looking closer to the way I'd like it but the narrow margin between the y-axis labels and the chart is driving me crazy. I was able to use negative line-spacing for the x-axis labels but obviously that won't work on y. I've tried messing around with the word-spacing but I'm striking out there as well.

The other thing I can't figure out is how to target the far left vertical line. I just need to match the color to the light gray horizontal lines.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish these?

Answer (score 0):

You provide no code and no screenshot, which probably explains the lack of interest your question has generated. If n is the name of your chart, the following will add space for y-axis label:

```
n$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
```